# How to debug low-level Android?

Tags: android, android-bluetooth

I need to debug some low-level stuff on an Android device. Specifically the Bluetooth Stack. So far I tried to figure out what's going on by just reading the source code and I saw that there are a lot of logging there which can be very helpful.

My problem is with how to enable them, the Bluetooth Stack has a file called **bt_stack.conf** which is located at */etc/bluetooth/*, I saw that this is used by the code to determine which log subsystems to enable. The problem is that I can't edit this file because of permissions, so I can't enable the logs.

One option would be to Root the device and edit the file, and I don't mind doing so on my development phone, but I will soon have to debug it on other phones as well. There must be better way to debug low level Android stuff other then rooting the phone using third-party tools.

How is it done usually by system level Android developers?

Comment: *How is it done usually by system level Android developers?* - Typically using debug builds of AOSP with extra logging and the ability to attach C debuggers. It'll prove a very difficult task on release builds.

Comment: @MichaelDodd I don't need a fully fledged debugger, just to enable the logs from a config text file which is readonly. Surely there are situations where they need to debug on release builds? Also, if I remember correctly it takes forever + 40 GB just to compile stock Android, not to mention multiple flavours for different phones

Comment: Yes, but remember the purpose of release builds - to prevent this sort of low level modification and poking causing problems for the end user. And yes, AOSP does take an absolutely age to compile from scratch, at least 2 hours with the `-j16` option, but is normally quick to recompile changes if you don't trash the build directory. If you can root and remount the system partition as read/write, then you may have luck, but if this isn't an option for other end-user devices then your remaining options are very limited.

Comment: Agree with Michael, it will be better to use userdebug system build for such debugging. Sometimes you need to modify Bluetooth source code to understand what happen (at least to add more logging). With usual firmware you can only analyze logcat and Bluetooth HCI snoop logs.